# Minimum iOS Deployment Target for Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, xcode6

Wikipedia said that the minimum `iOS` Deployment Target for `Xcode` 6's  was `iOS` 7. I just checked, with `XCode` 6 GM listed on the page now, the minimum `iOS` Deployment Target has been changed to `iOS` 5.1.1.

I do need to support `iOS` 6.0, and would like to confirm this with official `Xcode` document. I searched and could not find this particular information. Can someone share the link to an official document that mentions this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Xcode 6 supports a deployment target back to 4.3. Of course It doesn't support any simulators that old. You would need to test on real devices.

You will have no problem supporting back iOS 6 with Xcode 6 but you will need real devices with iOS 6 to test your app properly.

I don't have a link to a document but all you need do is set the project's Deployment Target to iOS 6.0 and you will have your proof.

Comment: That's great. I do not really need the document, as long as someone has tried and can confirm.

Comment: I will admit that my Deployment Target is now iOS 7.0 but I do have the option of selecting all the way back to 4.3 so I'm 99% sure you will have no issue supporting iOS 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 6 doesn't seem to even see my iPad 1. Although the deployment target is set to 5.1, the popup only shows 6.0 as the minimum in the popup.

Comment: I am able to build onto my iPad 1 from XCode 6

Comment: You are right. You need to manually add 5.1.1 as the minimum and then it will see the iPad 1.