# iOS 5.0 Deployment Support in XCode 6.1

Tags: ios, ios5, xcode6.1

I am working on XCode 6.1. I am fuzzy about iOS 5.0 deployment support, I am talking about Deployment Target. Please guide or provide any Apple Documentation Reference.

Comment: Confused in what way? What is the exact problem you are having?

Comment: @RoboticCat I want to communicate my client that iOS 5.0 Support is not available in Xcode 6.1. He is pushing me for Apple Official Link. I have troubles having support for iOS 5.0 support with Xcode 6.1. Unable to simulate iOS 5.0 also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [link](http://Check%20this%20[link][1],%20may%20this%20will%20help%20you.%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770115/minimum-), hope this will help you to sought out your problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770115/minimum-ios-deployment-target-for-xcode-6

Answer (score 0):

Under Target -> Build Settings -> Deployment Target, you can change it.

But you won't be able to test it on iOS 5/6 simulators. Only if you have devices with iOS 5/6 you can test the app.

Comment: Apple has stopped support for iOS5? isn't it?